# Save generatred Qr code to device using React-Native

Tags: react-native, qr-code

I am working on react native project I'm able to generate Qr code using `react-native-qrcode-svg`
Here the code How I have generated Qr code. I found answer where they suggest to store Qr to databse using key value but, I don't want to save Qr code to database. How do I save this generated Qr code as image to device ?

```
import React,{useRef} from "react";
import { StyleSheet, View, Text } from "react-native";
import ViewShot from "react-native-view-shot";
import QRCode from "react-native-qrcode-svg";
import Button from "../components/Button";

function QrGenerator({ navigation }) {
  let base64Logo = "data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAOEAA..";

  const deviceId = Expo.Constants.deviceId;
  const refs = useRef(null);

  var onSave = () => {
    refs.viewShot.capture().then((uri) => {
      Share.open({
        title: "QR Code",
        message: "message",
        url: uri, 
      });
    });
  };

  return (
    <View style={styles.MainContainer}>
      <ViewShot
        ref={refs}
        options={{ width: 100, height: 100, format: "jpg", quality: 1.0 }}
      >
        <View style={{ padding: 10, backgroundColor: "#FFFFFF" }}>
          <QRCode
            value={deviceId}
            logo={{ uri: base64Logo }}
            logoSize={80}
            logoBackgroundColor="transparent"
          />
        </View>
      </ViewShot>

      <Button title="Download" style={styles.Tbutton} onPress={() => onSave()} />
      <Button
        title="Back"
        style={styles.Tbutton}
        onPress={() => {
          navigation.navigate("splash");
        }}
      />
    </View>
  );
}
export default QrGenerator;

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  MainContainer: {
    flex: 1,
    margin: 10,
    alignItems: "center",
    paddingTop: 200,
  },
  text: {
    fontWeight: "bold",
    fontSize: 22,
    padding: 20,
  },
  Tbutton: {
    marginTop: 30,
    marginBottom: 8,
    padding: 13,
    borderRadius: 10,
    width: "60%",
  },
});
```

Comment: You mean to save QR code as an image?

Comment: @SaachiTech Yes

Answer (score 1):

You can save QR image locally. There're also several open source modules help you deal with file access if you want to store the images in file system.

[react-native-fs](https://github.com/itinance/react-native-fs)

[react-native-fetch-blob](https://github.com/wkh237/react-native-fetch-blob)

NOTE: **react-native-fetch-blob** has been discontinued. rn-fetch-blob is a fork of it that is still maintained. When using npm, don't include react-native-fetch-blob but rn-fetch-blob instead.

Comment: Sorry for unclear question but want to save Qr as Image to device.

Comment: I have read documentation about rn-fetch-blob but there are lots of things I couldn't figure out what exactly do i need to do because in documentation they are using fetch post and get method I don't think I'm doing get or post method.

Comment: Try this way RNFS.writeFile("destination_file_path..",base64_data, 'base64'); First need to create a file then try

Answer (score 1):

One of the way of doing this following.

Use react-native-view-shot to capture the qr image and then save or share it. Install and import it in your component

```
import ViewShot from "react-native-view-shot";
```

Create a ref

```
const viewShot = useRef(null);
```

Then wrap your qrcode View like this

```
<ViewShot ref={viewShot} options={{ width: 100, height: 100, format: "jpg", quality: 1.0 }}>
 <View style={{ padding: 10, backgroundColor: '#FFFFFF' }}>
  <QRCode
    value={ deviceId}
    logo={{ uri: base64Logo }}
    logoSize={80}
    logoBackgroundColor="transparent"
  />
 </View>
</ViewShot>
```

Now on your save button click, you can call this code and save generated uri using RNFS or use Share module for more options

```
onSave = () => {
 viewShot.current.capture().then(uri => {
  //Here you can write your logic of sharing or saving it on the device, I have used Share module 
  Share.open({
    title: "QR Code",
    message: "Any message",
    url: uri,
    subject: "Code" //  for email
  });
 });
}
```

Comment: I'm getting `TypeError: undefined is not an object (evaluating 'refs.viewShot.capture')`

Comment: I have update my solution but still getting error .

Comment: May be an issue with `ref`, it’s from old code so might not work with latest React version. I will update soon

Comment: Are you using functional component or class component?

Comment: I'm using functional component with useState hooks

Comment: Updated my answer

Comment: `[Unhandled promise rejection: ReferenceError: Can't find variable: Share]` i'm getting this error

Comment: Please read my comment over code, I mentioned you can use any logic to save it. I used `Share` which you will have to install and import if you want to use it. From my answer you now have base64 image uri which can be used in any way.

Comment: `npm i share` is this the one i'm supposed to use ?

Comment: Instead try https://react-native-share.github.io/react-native-share/docs/install/